# Top Words per Topic

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I'm doing textual analysis in Python based on emails I received. My data is in a Pandas dataframe, with the text of the email in `df['document']` and the topic is in the column `df['topic']`.

I want to create a dataframe with the top keywords that define each topic (possibly using tf_idf).

I created a vectorizer and I'm trying to create a new dataframe with the topic as the index or row, and the list of words in the column.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
v = TfidfVectorizer()
x = v.fit_transform(df['document'])

# Topic-Keyword Matrix
df_topic_keywords = pd.DataFrame()

# Assign Column and Index
df_topic_keywords.columns = v.get_feature_names() #error occurs here
df_topic_keywords.index = df['topic']

# View
df_topic_keywords.head()
```

I then get the error.

> "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values
>   have 12730166 elements"

Comment: On which line do you get this error!!

Comment: I get the error here: df_topic_keywords.columns = v.get_feature_names()

Comment: this `v.get_feature_names()` should be a list. is it a list ?

Comment: yes, it's a list. I ran type() on it.

Comment: @abobmz: Does my answer helped you ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, no, but I think I need to rephrase the question. I have a pandas dataframe with text in one column and the topic in the other (someone before me conducted a word embedding/LDA). Is there a way to generate the top five keywords grouped by topic and add it as a new column in the dataframe? Thank you for all your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is you have made a new df with zero columns and trying to assign new column in it. The solution to this is:

```
 df_topic_keywords = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.empty((0, len(v.get_feature_names()))))
 df_topic_keywords.columns = v.get_feature_names()
```